# how to update value in data.table based on condition (date) in r

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update the value in dt based on the most recent date.

```
dt <- data.table(Name=c('John Smith', 'John Doe', 'Jeff Smith'),
             State=c('MI','WI','WI'), 
             Date = c("2018-1-2", "2018-1-4", "2018-1-6"),
             stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: could you specify ? what value do you want to update and with what ? Most recent date in the whole data.table, or per group ? which group ?

Comment: add a 3 to the name of the person from WI with the most recent date.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
dt[State == "WI" & Date == dt[which.max(as.POSIXct(Date)), Date], Name := paste0(Name, "3")]
```